# Where is the source for the Ezrat Nashim and Ezrat Israel in the Temple?

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash

Sorry for my ignorance, all sources I know speak of the de-facto existence of the two Azarot in the Temple and their measures.

I would like to understand whether those parts are an intrinsic part of the original and divine plan of the temple (as some interpreters try to solve their measures) or a part of second-temple era architectural design.

Where are those this learned from? Were those present in the Mishkan or the first Temple?

Comment: There was also עזרת כהנים.

Comment: @msh210 Ezrat Kohanim is self-evident from the Mishkan. The other two were missing, hence the question.